# Mysql show processlist lists many processes sleep and info = null?

Tags: mysql

I'm injecting a stress test into my web app that connects to a mysql server and I'm monitoring the show processlist of mysql.

When the load is high (high swap i/o) I get many processes like that:

```
| 97535 | db| localhost | userA | Sleep   |  515 |         | NULL 
| 97536 | db| localhost | userA | Sleep   |  516 |         | NULL 
| 97786 | db| localhost | userA | Sleep   |  343 |         | NULL 
| 97889 | db| localhost | userA | Sleep   |  310 |         | NULL
```

But I can't understand why are they still there and are not killed? This eventually leads to my app using all max_connections and stop processing incoming requests...

Any idea what are those processes and what are they doing there :) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those are idle connections being held by a client.  You should make sure that whatever client library you are using (JDBC, ...) is configured to not keep unused connections open so long, or that your # clients * max # of connections isn't too big.

Comment: is there any mysql timeout variable that i can adjust to avoid this?

Comment: You can set wait_timeout to something smaller (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) or raise the connection limit.  You really want to solve this on the application side, however.  Hanging up the connection from the database side risks closing a connection just as the application tries to use it, potentially causing an application error for no good reason.  What database connection library are you using?

Comment: @KeithRandall but how to identify the Null processes?

Comment: @Khuram: What do you mean?  They are listed in `show processlist`, you get the ip address it connects from and the username used, if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you are using persistent connections, e.g. [pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) in php:

> [..] when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection

and

> [..] the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the **link will remain open** for future use

I had a similar situation, and was using Codeigniter with pconnect turned on. After turning it to off ([see how](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html)) every connection was closed down properly after use, and my MySQL processlist was empty.

**Performance**: The above does not argue about performance, but simply tries to explain why you might see a lot of Sleeping connections in MySQL. It might not be negative, with regard to performance, to have the connections stay active.
More info at: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/