# SQL, PHP - Close a sleeping connection

Tags: sql, mysql, database-connection, sleep

Good day to all. I have a little problem:

How do I close the sleeping connections to a database?

When I issue a query the query is executed then the connection remains on sleep mode for 2-3 seconds. The problem is that I generate queries faster than they are closed.

Is there a way to force a connection to close before entering in the sleep mode? Or any workaround.

Thank you for help.

Note: The connections are not permanent, they close, but just to slow...
Note 2 - for the mysql_close(): The command is issued at the end of the query. Still the query goes into sleep mode before close. I attach a print screen in a min.

[image]

Notice the sleeping connections... they will be closed in 1-3 secs... but I generate another queries faster. I need to skip the sleep wasted time.

Comment: are you talking about a thread saying SLEEP when you run SHOW PROCESSLIST?

Comment: yes - sleeps = finished query...  waiting for whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using mysql_pconnect() ? If not, this should not happen if you properly close every connection made to your database.

Edit : [Similar issue ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053744/mysql-show-processlist-lists-many-processes-sleep-and-info-null)

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly. For example, if you are using mysql then call mysql_close(). Or the equivalent for whatever database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

my class for dbconnection hast `mysqli_close($this->conn);`
in its `__destruct()` so that every connection is closed on destruction of the connection.

Comment: I also do this... is not fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **wait_timeout** variable = 1 so they will close after 1 second.