# What could cause all the MySQL connections to sleep?

Tags: mysql, connection, sleep

For some reason,the connections to my local database are put to sleep, even though the database is not actually doing anything:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db  | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+-----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|  85 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  810 |       | NULL                  |
|  88 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  662 |       | NULL                  |
|  89 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  586 |       | NULL                  |
|  93 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  692 |       | NULL                  |
|  98 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  719 |       | NULL                  |
| 102 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  545 |       | NULL                  |
| 182 | root | localhost | *** | Query   |    0 | init  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
| 263 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  809 |       | NULL                  |
| 275 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  660 |       | NULL                  |
| 279 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  584 |       | NULL                  |
| 282 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |    1 |       | NULL                  |
| 283 | root | localhost | *** | Sleep   |  544 |       | NULL                  |
+-----+------+-----------+-----+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

No new connections are being made and there's no lock, but somehow the requests are not being processed. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using a connection pool?

Comment: Google to the rescue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053744/mysql-show-processlist-lists-many-processes-sleep-and-info-null

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql Proccesslist filled with "Sleep" Entries leading to "Too many Connections"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407732/mysql-proccesslist-filled-with-sleep-entries-leading-to-too-many-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context `Sleep` simply means that the thread is idle. Here's the definition from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/thread-commands.html):

> - **Sleep**
>
> The thread is waiting for the client to send a new statement to it.

Answer (score 0):

By default PHP is configured to allow persistent MySQL connections.  That's why you're seeing all these sleeping connections, just waiting to be re-used.

Whether you want to use persistent links or not is a different question, but if you want to disable it then you need to make a change to your PHP.ini

```
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
```